# Getting a single value with the PerformanceEntry API

Tags: javascript, performance

When I try to get the page load time using PerformanceEntry I'm able to get an array of data but how do i get only the value of "domComplete" or "duration" instead of the whole list of data; Here's the code:

```
const time = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
console.log(time[0]);
console.log(time[0]['domComplete']);
```

when i console log (time[0]), this is what i get:

[image]

but when using (time[0]['domComplete']) or (time[0]['duration']), it returns 0

[image]

Comment: see that blue square with an i.... that means the data loaded after. Hover over it. You are reading it before the data is there.

Comment: Ohh okay, it worked now after I did put in on an unload event

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
console.log(time[0].domComplete);
```